# Python anonymization using random.shuffle a list in a list

Tags: python, list, shuffle

Here is my coding:

```
word = ma['vals']
shuffled = list(word)                   
random.shuffle(word)
shuffled = ''.join(random.sample(word, len(word)))                      
newval = shuffled
```

the result will be `BALLOONSFLOWERSGIFTSFLOWERSCANDYFLOWERSBALLOONSBALLOONS`. When I want the result to be for eg if i'm shuffling `gifts`, e result will be `stgfi`.

Comment: i think i should edit my codings. [balloons, flowers, gifts, candy] is actually retrieved out from database.

Comment: Could you phrase this more like a question? It's not clear what's being asked.

Comment: right now the output is not being shuffled but it is being add on. what i wants is the attribute to be shuffled individually.

Comment: Btw. Shuffling things doesn't make them anonymous.

Answer (score 3):

*This is too long for a comment, so I'll put it in as an answer, although it isn't.*

I'm sorry, please don't take this the wrong way, but this is the worst code I've seen in 15 years. You should probably go through a basic tutorial at least once more to get a better grip on what is happening, because this feels to me like you are just randomly typing things without trying to understand what they do.

Let's start from the beginning:

```
ma['vals'] = [balloons, flowers, gifts, candy]
```

OK, so I assume ma is a dictionary. You use that dictionary nowehere in the code. Why is it there?

```
word = ma['vals']
```

Now you just set word to `[balloons, flowers, gifts, candy]`. Why not do that directly? Also, don't call a list of words "word".  That implies that it is *one* word, but you made it a list.

```
shuffled = list(word)
```

Why do you do list(word)? It's already a list. All you have done now is set:

```
shuffled = [balloons, flowers, gifts, candy]
```

And you call it shuffled, when it's not.

```
random.shuffle(word)
```

And now you shuffle it. But you didn't use the shuffled variable, you used the word variable.

```
shuffled = ''.join(random.sample(word, len(word)))
```

And now you set `shuffled` to another thing, so you never *used* the first `shuffled`. besides, making a random sample from a list that is as long as the list, is the same things as shuffling it, and the list is already shuffled.

```
newval = shuffled
```

Why did you do this?

All your code can in fact be compressed into:

```
newval = [balloons, flowers, gifts, candy]
random.shuffle(newval)
```

This will have the same end result: You will have a randomly shuffled list of words.

So two thirds of your code actually end up not doing *anything*. The above also makes it quite clear why your code doesn't behave like you think. You shuffle a list of words, when you want to shuffle a word.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to randomly choose a word, and then randomly shuffle the letters of that word:

```
In [27]: letters = list(random.choice(word))

In [28]: random.shuffle(letters)

In [29]: ''.join(letters)
Out[29]: 'blanolos'
```

Here, `word` is the same variable as in your script (i.e. the *list* of words).

Answer (score 1):

You must create a list from a string. In your case for example, the string "balloons" would be accessed by `ma["vals"][0]`. You can then convert this to a list via calling `list` and passing in the string. The named optional paramter `random` to the function `random.shuffle` is the function based on which the sorting occurs. `random.shuffle` modifies the list passed into `random.shuffle` in place, hence why you call `join` on the list and not the result of the call to `random.shuffle`.

```
>>> wordList = list(ma["vals"][0])) #"balloons"
>>> random.shuffle(wordList,random=random.random)
>>> ''.join(wordList)
'oboanlls'
```

Comment: Oops, I was updating the code to access "balloons" via the dictionary instead if having a literal there and copied a but extra!